# How do I draw rice grains in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What techniques would you use for drawing rice grains in Photoshop?

Comment: Does "very carefully" count as an answer? This seems very specific. You might want to ask a question about a technique rather than something so specific as drawing grains of rice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Take a photo of some rice.
   Alternately, throw some rice on your
   scanner and scan it.
2. Open the image.
3. Trace it.

Comment: Actually, I used the pen tool and layer styles.